# Postgres: add description of an ENUM value?

Tags: django, postgresql, enums

I've got an `ENUM` column in Postgres 9.6:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS ENUM('foo', 'bar');
```

I'd like to add a human-readable description for each value in the enum, e.g. for `foo`, `This is the foo value and it does stuff`.

Is there any way to do this in Postgres? I'd like something like Django's [choices field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices).

Answer (score 5):

Nothing fancy can be done I think. Standard `comment`?..

```
t=# \x
Expanded display is on.
t=# comment on type my_type is 'foo: something fooish, bar: a place to avoid';
COMMENT
t=# \dT+ my_type
List of data types
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+---------------------------------------------
Schema            | public
Name              | my_type
Internal name     | my_type
Size              | 4
Elements          | foo                                         +
                  | bar
Owner             | postgres
Access privileges |
Description       | foo: something fooish, bar: a place to avoid
```

with some nerd sniping:

```
t=# comment on type my_type is '{"foo": "something fooish", "bar": "a place to avoid"}';
COMMENT
t=# select pg_catalog.obj_description(t.oid, 'pg_type')::json->>'foo' from pg_type t where typname = 'my_type';
     ?column?
------------------
 something fooish
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Teoretically you can create two type with same dimension and use something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS ENUM('foo', 'bar');
CREATE TYPE my_type_description AS ENUM('foo desc', 'bar desc');

CREATE FUNCTION show_desc(i my_type) RETURNS my_type_description AS $sql$
    SELECT ((enum_range(NULL::my_type_description))[array_length(enum_range(NULL, i), 1)])::my_type_description;
$sql$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;

SELECT show_desc('foo');

 show_desc 
-----------
 foo desc
(1 row)

SELECT show_desc('bar');

 show_desc 
-----------
 bar desc
(1 row)
```